# mysql get data from a specific week

Tags: mysql

I was able to get the different weeks using the following query

```
  SELECT FROM_DAYS( TO_DAYS(  `time` ) - MOD( TO_DAYS(  `time` ) -2, 7 ) ) AS week
FROM  `exchange` 
WHERE  `id` >25262
GROUP BY week
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

For example could be `2015-03-02`

I have placed this in a while loop to extract the data

Now I would like to run a query like the following

```
Select count(`id`) FROM `exchange`  WHERE `time`  = **week**
```

I want to select data where the row is a particular. I cant get it working properly. Please help.

Comment: Did you try the week() function?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: I dont get a week number but "2015-03-02", for example... so how can I use that piece of data?

Comment: If 2015-03-02 is the first day of your week, then it's easy to compute the last day of it and search into that interval

Comment: Could you help me do that? how can I add 7 days to it?